# Android Studio Emulator shows titlebar but designer does not

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

Like title says. The android emulator is displaying the title bar, however in my designer the title bar is not their so when I launch the emulator it inserts the title bar and shifts everything down. Is there a setting in android studio that will display the title bar?

Thanks

Comment: I think your designer may use a app theme that is not action bar.So change your designer's app theme.

Comment: Where is the app theme changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stub layouts, texts, images etc. you can use `tools` XML namespace. It only works in Android Studio's designer tool. In your final application, nothing will be visible.

For instance, this code stubs content of `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Hello!"
    />
```

Do not forget to declare namespace at your root element:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="..."
    xmlns:tools="..."
    />
```